# Unit testing a plugin in Nuxt 3

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've created a relatively simple plugin which is responsible for making an api call, and receives a base URL to prepend to the endpoint, following the instructions here: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-nuxt-app/

My plugin:

```
import { $fetch } from "ohmyfetch";
import {useRuntimeConfig} from "#app";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig();
    nuxtApp.provide('apiFetch', $fetch.create({baseURL: config.BASE_URL}))
});
```

I want to use Jest to unit test this plugin, just to follow best practices and ensure that any changes in the future won't affect it. For context, the way this is going to be used in a component is

`const posts = await useNuxtApp().$apiFetch('/api/prints');`

I have no idea how to replicate this in my test file, as all I need to do is call the plugin with some params, and check that fetch is called with the params I would expect - or better still, mock some data for the api endpoint, and check that what's expected is returned.

I'm having problems understanding how to inject the plugin into nuxt and then call it. Older versions of Jest used `createLocalVue`, but I'm unsure how to do this in Nuxt 3.

This is all I've got so far, which gives me this error: `TypeError: (0 , _app_1.useNuxtApp) is not a function`

I'm assuming I'll have to do some mocking somewhere, but am unsure how or of what.

```
import { useNuxtApp } from "#app";

it('calls fetch with correct endpoint', async() => {
    await useNuxtApp().$apiFetch
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Did you solve your problem? I also got a very simple Nuxt plugin and I want to check if one method of my plugin is getting called correctly in a test, but I dont know how to mock this plugin :(